# Custom class object and "in" set operator

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.6. Suppose that I'm trying to keep a unique set of tuples. I know I can use `tuple in set` and get back the correct result (the set contains the tuple or not).

```py
s = set()
t1 = (1, 2)
t2 = (1, 2)
s.add(t1)
print(t2 in s) # True -- Great!
```

Now, suppose I have a custom class that contains a tuple. I would like to define uniqueness for the custom class objects as uniqueness for the tuple. I did the following:

```py
class TupleWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t # tuple

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.t)


s = set()
t1 = TupleWrapper((1, 2))
s.add(t1)
t2 = TupleWrapper((1, 2))
print(t2 in s) # False -- WHY?
```

I wrote my own `__hash__()` method that hashes the tuple. So why are the two `TupleWrapper` objects with the same tuple not found to be the same in the `set`? Do I need to override another method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to implement `__eq__` on `TupleWrapper` as well.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, TupleWrapper):
        return self.t == other.t
    return NotImplemented
```

otherwise, when checking to see if the object is already in the set, it will default to identity comparison, which is just `is` (i.e., `t1 is t2` or `id(t1) == id(t2)`).

more detail: loosely speaking, on insertion, `set` (and `dict`) first use the hash value to figure out which bucket things are in. then, in that bucket, it uses `==` to check, in the case of a hash collision, if that object is already there.

hash documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Comment: Thank you. How would I know that `thing in set` would call `thing.__eq__(other)`? Is it documented clearly somewhere?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: `__eq__` is the overload hook for `==` equality comparisons.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 for starters, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Also, the [definition of hashable in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) which is linked to from the [documentation for sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)